# Rank column with arrayformula and cull duplicates based on another column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling with a Google Sheets arrayformula. I want to make an arrayformula to show rank position of Column B values (TOT). With my formula I just achieve a copy of the first position. I don't want duplicate values in the rank, so if there is two equal values the Column A sets the priority.

```
={"POS";ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2$B:$B<>"";RANK.EQ(B3;B3:B42;0)))}
```

**Test Document:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzs1nvpzG0VgygxbXF9bKxvGaAq-H29oI1aquupYNFc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What would be your desired output from given sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in cell `C2`, it will rank them as you're trying to do. If you wanted to match the other direction (lowest to highest), then swith the sort parameter from `false` to `true`.

```
=Filter(match(B2:B+(A2:A/1000),
Sort(Filter(B2:B+A2:A/1000,B2:B<>""),1,false),0),A2:A<>"")
```

You also appear to have duplicates including in column A (example see rows 4,25,35). If you wanted to exclude the duplicates (effectively reducing the number of ranked values),  This can be done using the unique function which would create a 17 in each row.

```
=Filter(match(B2:B+(A2:A/1000),
Unique(Sort(Filter(B2:B+A2:A/1000,B2:B<>""),1,false),0)),A2:A<>"")
```

[image]